# Install npm dependencies for specific node version using package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-lambda

On my local environment, I'm using the latest `node` version but during the deployment of my AWS Lambda function I have to use `v8.10.0`.

I have created `.nvmrc` file with `v8.10.0` set and to install node_modules I simply run:

```
nvm exec npm i
```

The problem that it is not using `package-lock.json` at all - which is even altered by `npm i` command.

`node v8.10.0` delivers `npm v5.6.0` which doesn't provide `npm ci` command.

Is there any other way to install dependencies for `v8.10.0` using lock file?

Comment: could you run `npm update npm@lastest -g` after installing node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, in versions of npm after 5.0 (specifically, 5.4 and onward), "npm install" *can* update the package lock file, and there is no option to avoid this behavior.

In npm >=6.0, you can use `npm ci`, which installs only from the package lock file, which is what you want. (See https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17979 and https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18286 for a lot of backstory/history.)

If you can use node v8.14 instead of v8.10, you'll get npm@6 out of the box. If not, you might be up the creek.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `npm shrinkwrap` ? IIRC package-lock.json has been changed to npm-shrinkwrap.json, but I can't remember in which version

That is, run `npm install && npm shrinkwrap` and make sure the resulting json gets committed into your repo / transferred to AWS